# Flutter: Why is website not showing images?

Tags: android, webview, flutter

I am using the webview_flutter package to show a website in the app itself. When pressing the button in a previous screen the new page "LookBook" is opening and after a short time (think it takes too long) it is opening the website. Only the images of the website are not shown. Think it has to do with the SSL certificate but I do not know if this is true and how to solve it. Maybe someone can help me?

[image: Image in webview not shown]

Comment: What URL are you using? Are the images using the same protocol as the HTML page itself (HTTP vs HTTPS)?

Comment: When using http I get the result as shown in the image. When using https the webview stays completely white. When opening the website on my laptop in safari the url starts with https. The website is sprokkelbos.nl. I am new to android studio and flutter (made 2 apps with xcode, there in the app store) but struggling a bit to get familiar with using it.